# Why am I getting this error in my schema in postman: Schema is valid | AssertionError: Unknown property (not in schema): expected false to equal true

Tags: javascript, schema, postman

Hi I am writing schema for a method called GetDistanceTravelled/{id}/{date}.  I know its not an array so I know that much as can be concluded in the response body. I have checked the id and date are valid.  But I seem to get this error when running my schema Schema is valid | AssertionError: Unknown property (not in schema): expected false to equal true.  With a second pair of eyes or more can you see where I am going wrong please.

The body response is below:

```
{
    "DistanceInMiles": 4.26,
    "DistanceInKm": 6.85580544
}
```

The schema is below:

```
tests['Status code is 200'] = pm.response.to.have.status(200);
var schema = {
    "items" : {  
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "DistanceInMiles": {"type": "number" },
            "DistanceInKm": {"type": "number"  },
        }
    }
};
pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
    var response = pm.response.json();
    var result = tv4.validateResult(response, schema, false, true);
    pm.expect(result.valid).to.equal(true, result.valid ? null : result.error.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tests['Status code is 200'] = pm.response.to.have.status(200);
var schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "DistanceInMiles": {"type": "number" },
        "DistanceInKm": {"type": "number"  },
    }

};
pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
var response = pm.response.json();
var result = tv4.validateResult(response, schema, false, true);
pm.expect(result.valid).to.equal(true, result.valid ? null :            result.error.message);
});
```

Comment: After some thorough research it was simply a case of removing the items property.  As a newbie I hope it helps others